# Convert numbers in text (.csv) file from one locale format to another?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a .csv file, in which the numbers are formatted according to `da_DK` locale (i.e. a comma is used instead of a period as decimal point separator, among other things), so it looks something like this:

```
"5000","0,00","5,25", ....
```

I'd like to use a command line application to convert all the numbers in the file in one go, so the output is "C" (or POSIX) locale (i.e. dot/period is used as decimal separator):

```
"5000","0.00","5.25", ....
```

... keeping the decimal places as they are (i.e. "0,00" should be converted to "0.00", not "0" or "0.") and leaving all other data/formatting unchanged.

I am aware that there is [numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html), which should allow something like:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_DK.utf8 numfmt --from=iec --grouping 22123,11
22.123,11
```

... however, `numfmt` can only convert between units, not locales (once `LC_ALL` is specified, also the input number has to conform to it, just like the output).

I'd ultimately like something that is CSV-agnostic - that is, can parse through a text file, find all substrings that match a format of a number in the given input locale (i.e. the program would deduce from a string like `"5000","0,00","5,25","hello"....` three locale-specific numeric substrings `5000`, `0,00` and `5,25`), convert and replace these substrings, and leave everything else as is; but as an alternative, I'd also like to know about a CSV-aware approach (i.e., all fields are parsed row by row, and then content of each field is checked if it matches a locale-specific numeric string).

Answer (score 0):

updated: this will convert numbers.numbers to numbersnumbers and numbers,numbers to numbers.numbers for any text:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)/\1\2/g' -e 's/\([0-9]\+\),\([0-9]\+\)/\1.\2/g'

Orig string: "AO900-020","Hello","World","5000","0,00","5,25","stk","","1","0,00","Test 2","42.234,12","","","0,00","","","","5,25"
Conv string: "AO900-020","Hello","World","5000","0.00","5.25","stk","","1","0.00","Test 2","42234.12","","","0.00","","","","5.25"
```

(same example i/o as OP's `perl` answer)

note: this would be very bad if you have any unquoted fields in your csv.

Comment: i've updated so that it now removes (grouping) dots from numbers before converting commas to dots.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did find a way to do this in Perl, and it's not exactly trivial; an example (csv-agnostic) script which converts a test string is pasted below. Ultimately it prints:

```
Orig string: "AO900-020","Hello","World","5000","0,00","5,25","stk","","1","0,00","Test 2","42.234,12","","","0,00","","","","5,25"
Conv string: "AO900-020","Hello","World","5000","0.00","5.25","stk","","1","0.00","Test 2","42234.12","","","0.00","","","","5.25"
```

... which is basically what I wanted to achieve; but there may be edge cases here which would be undesirable. Maybe better to use something like this with a tool like `csvfix` or `csvtool`, or use a Perl csv library directly in code.

Still, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use locale;
use POSIX qw(setlocale locale_h LC_ALL);
use utf8;
use Number::Format qw(:subs); # sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Number::Format'
use Data::Dumper;
use Scalar::Util::Numeric qw(isint); # sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Scalar::Util::Numeric'

my $old_locale;

# query and save the old locale
$old_locale = setlocale(LC_ALL);

# list of (installed) locales: bash$ locale -a
setlocale(LC_ALL, "POSIX");

# localeconv() returns "a reference to a hash of locale-dependent info"
# dereference here:
#%posixlocalesettings = %{localeconv()};
#print Dumper(\%posixlocalesettings);

# or without dereference:
my $posixlocalesettings = localeconv();
# the $posixlocalesettings has only 'decimal_point' => '.';
# force also thousands_sep to '', else it will be comma later on, and grouping will be made regardless
$posixlocalesettings->{'thousands_sep'} = '';
print Dumper($posixlocalesettings);

#~ my $posixNumFormatter = new Number::Format %args;    
# thankfully, Number::Format seems to accept as argument same kind of hash that localeconv() returns:
my $posixNumFormatter = new Number::Format(%{$posixlocalesettings});
print Dumper($posixNumFormatter);


setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_DK.utf8");
my $dklocalesettings = localeconv();
print Dumper($dklocalesettings);

# Get some of locale's numeric formatting parameters
my ($thousands_sep, $decimal_point, $grouping) =
#        @{localeconv()}{'thousands_sep', 'decimal_point', 'grouping'};
        @{$dklocalesettings}{'thousands_sep', 'decimal_point', 'grouping'};

# grouping and mon_grouping are packed lists
# of small integers (characters) telling the
# grouping (thousand_seps and mon_thousand_seps
# being the group dividers) of numbers and
# monetary quantities.  The integers’ meanings:
# 255 means no more grouping, 0 means repeat
# the previous grouping, 1-254 means use that
# as the current grouping.  Grouping goes from
# right to left (low to high digits).  In the
# below we cheat slightly by never using anything
# else than the first grouping (whatever that is).
my @grouping = unpack("C*", $grouping);
print "en_DK.utf8: thousands_sep $thousands_sep; decimal_point $decimal_point; grouping " .join(", ", @grouping). "\n";

my $inputCSVString = '"AO900-020","Hello","World","5000","0,00","5,25","stk","","1","0,00","Test 2","42.234,12","","","0,00","","","","5,25"';

# Character set modifiers
# /d, /u , /a , and /l , available starting in 5.14, are called the character set modifiers;
#  /l sets the character set to that of whatever Locale is in effect at the time of the execution of the pattern match.

while ($inputCSVString =~ m/[[:digit:]]+/gl) { # doesn't take locale in account
  print "A Found '$&'.  Next attempt at character " . (pos($inputCSVString)+1) . "\n";
}

print "----------\n";


#~ while ($inputCSVString =~ m/(\d{$grouping[0]}($|$thousands_sep))+/gl) {
#~ while ($inputCSVString =~ m/(\d)(\d{$grouping[0]}($|$thousands_sep))+/gl) {
# match a string that starts with digit, and contains only digits, thousands separators and decimal points
# note - it will NOT match negative numbers
while ($inputCSVString =~ m/\d[\d$thousands_sep$decimal_point]+/gl) {
  my $numstrmatch = $&;
  my $unnumstr = unformat_number($numstrmatch); # should unformat according to current locale ()
  my $posixnumstr = $posixNumFormatter->format_number($unnumstr);
  print "B Found '$numstrmatch' (unf: '$unnumstr', form: '$posixnumstr').  Next attempt at character " . (pos($inputCSVString)+1) . "\n";
}

sub convertNumStr{
  my $numstrmatch = $_[0];
  my $unnumstr = unformat_number($numstrmatch);
  # if an integer, return as is so it doesn't change trailing zeroes, if the number is a label
  if ( (isint $unnumstr) && ( $numstrmatch !~ m/$decimal_point_dk/) ) { return $numstrmatch; }
  #~ print "--- $unnumstr\n";
  # find the length of the string after the decimal point - the precision
  my $precision_strlen = length( substr( $numstrmatch, index($numstrmatch, $decimal_point_dk)+1 ) );
  # must manually spec precision and trailing zeroes here:
  my $posixnumstr = $posixNumFormatter->format_number($unnumstr, $precision_strlen, 1);
  return $posixnumstr;
}

# e modifier to evaluate perl Code
(my $replaceString = $inputCSVString) =~ s/(\d[\d$thousands_sep$decimal_point]+)/"".convertNumStr($1).""/gle;

print "Orig string: " . $inputCSVString . "\n";
print "Conv string: " . $replaceString . "\n";
```